# How to properly define an object within definition and reference in multiple places for Json Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to create a json schema wherein I have an object within a definition & this definition is called within multiple places.
I see an error saying `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: duplicate type name: Location`

I have the below code.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "definitions": {
    "holiday": {
      "description": "A collection of time off associated with the employee.",
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "object",
          "nullable": true,
          "title": "Location",
          "properties": {
            "city": {
              "type": "string",
              "nullable": true,
              "tsType": "string | null",
              "description": ""
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }

  },
  "description": "The model for the employee object received on the Ingress API.",
  "properties": {
    "eventType": {
      "avroType": "string",
      "enum": ["EMPLOYEE_TIMEOFF_CREATED", "EMPLOYEE_CREATED_OR_UPDATED"],
      "tsEnumNames": ["EmployeeTimeOffCreated", "EmployeeCreatedOrUpdated"],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "employeeCreatedOrUpdated": {
      "description": "Event data for a employee create request.",
      "required": ["code", "firstName", "lastName"],
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "description": "A unique code for an employee.",
          "minLength": 1,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "firstName": {
          "description": "This field describes the first name of the employee.",
          "minLength": 1,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "middleName": {
          "description": "This field describes the middle name of the employee.",
          "nullable": true,
          "tsType": "string | null",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
          "description": "This field describes the last name of the employee.",
          "minLength": 1,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "timeOff": {
          "description": "A collection of employee time off associated with the employee.",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/holiday"
          },
          "nullable": true,
          "type": "array"
        }
      },
      "title": "EmployeeCreatedOrUpdated",
      "type": "object"
    },

    "employeeTimeOffCreated": {
      "description": "Event data for an employee time off created request.",
      "required": ["timeOffCreated", "employeeCode"],
      "$id": "https://io.something/v2/employee/employeeTimeOffCreated",
      "properties": {
        "timeOffCreated": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/holiday"
        },
        "employeeCode": {
          "description": "A unique code for an employee.",
          "minLength": 1,
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "title": "EmployeeTimeOffCreated",
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "required": ["eventType"],
  "title": "EmployeeEvent",
  "type": "object"
}
```

So, I use the `holiday` definition at two places. I tried to have an `id` within `$ref` but that doesn't work. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the `$id` property you're using in `employeeTimeOffCreated`. According to the [spec](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#id), it is only allowed in the root. Does it work without?

Comment: @Byted, no it's not working. Also tried to add `$id` to the definition, still it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Json thanks for the edits, the sample looks more prettier now. Any advise on the above question?

Comment: Can you add what implementation you're using please? =]

Answer (score 1):

Here's your schema reduced to only the parts needed to understand the problem.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "employeeCreatedOrUpdated": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "timeOff": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/holiday" }
        }
      }
    },
    "employeeTimeOffCreated": {
      "$id": "https://io.something.ingress/v2/employee/employeeTimeOffCreated",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "timeOffCreated": { "$ref": "#/definitions/holiday" }
      }
    }
  }

  "definitions": {
    "holiday": true
  }
}
```

When you use `$id` in a sub-schema like this, it indicates that the sub-schema is a completely separate schema embedded in the parent schema. Any references inside of the embedded schema are relative the the `$id`, not the parent schema. So, the reference at "timeOffCreated" expects `#/definitions/holiday` relative to the embedded schema. There's nothing there, so you get an error.

If you don't need "employeeTimeOffCreated" to be an embedded schema, the easiest thing is to remove `$id` and your references will work. Otherwise, you can give `/definitions/holiday` an `$id` as well and reference with that URI instead.

Embedded schemas are really only good for bundling schemas for distribution. Otherwise, you probably want to maintain separate schemas for each of your entities and just reference other schemas when you need them.

Here's what it would look like neatly bundled. If you want to work on these as separate schemas as suggested, you just need to extract each of the definitions into their own schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://io.something.ingress/v2/employee",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "employeeCreatedOrUpdated": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "timeOff": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "./holiday" }
        }
      }
    },
    "employeeTimeOffCreated": { "$ref": "./employeeTimeOffCreated" }
  }

  "definitions": {
    "employeeTimeOffCreated": {
      "$id": "./employeeTimeOffCreated",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "timeOffCreated": { "$ref": "./holiday" }
      }
    },
    "holiday": {
      "$id": "./holiday",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Additional reference: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#bundling

Comment: Giving give `/definitions/holiday` an $id doesn't work @Jason

Comment: Did you update the `$ref` as well? Just adding the `$id` isn't enough. If this doesn't work, for you, there's a bug in the implementation you're using.